# UINavigationBar appearance attributes not working on iOS 8

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios8

I used to change the title properties(font, textColor etc.) or the Nativgation Bar of my app, by using the code below:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil]];`
```

Today I just noticed that on iOS8 GM Seed, the textColor doesn't change, and remains as black.

Much appreciated help if anybody has had a similar issue, and resolved it.

Comment: It is working. Will you please provide more code piece? Are you setting that in appDelegate?

Comment: @Goppinath: I was adding that code in viewWillAppear, after shifting the code to AppDelegate, the problem seems to have been resolved

Answer (score 6):

`UITextAttributeTextColor` is deprecated. Use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
```

A little more readable:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

In your case into the ViewController use it as follow:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
}
```

With appearance you have to take the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`  inside AppDelegate.

Comment: Hello Matz,
Thank you for the comment, although I still see black color for my navigation title :(

I'm writing this code in the viewWillAppear: method of the ViewController, which is displayed as the RootViewController of the app.

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.navigationItem.title = @"My App";
    

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];

}`

Comment: This was good answer, plus One for readability option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After looking into @Matz answer, I used NSForegroundColorAttributeName attribute. 
Although I had to port the code from viewWillAppear: method of my UIViewController class, to App Delegate, after that it just worked.